# Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' on DropdownButton

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I'm creating DropdownButton from API. The dropdown list has been shown as I need, but the problem is the list I selected is not shown as well, and the error shows when I click the list:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Here is my variable declaration:

```dart
String _provinceSelected;
```

Here is my DropdownButton Widget:

```dart
DropdownButton(
  hint: Text('your province'),
  itemHeight: 60,
  isExpanded: true,
  items: dataProvince.map((item) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(item['name']),
      value: item['id'],
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _provinceSelected = value;
    });
  },
  value: _provinceSelected,
),
```

Is there any thing wrong on my code? Please help?

Comment: what is the `item` object?

Comment: The item is List<dynamic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any thing wrong on my code?

There is a type mismatch.

The type variable `_provinceSelected` is defined to be of type `String`, however when the value is assigned it assigned to a type of `int`, due to `item['id']` being an `int`.

Update the `DropdownButton` to set a `Type` value like this `DropdownButton<String>` and update the value definition to be a `String`.

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
  hint: Text('your province'),
  itemHeight: 60,
  isExpanded: true,
  items: dataProvince.map((item) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(item['name']),
      value: item['id'].toString(),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _provinceSelected = value;
    });
  },
  value: _provinceSelected,
),
```

Comment: I have tried to convert the variable to int _provinceSelected, but still not work.

Comment: Another error appears:
[link](https://postimg.cc/tsCGq4Qy)

Comment: Non-Unique values were given to `DropdownButton`, it seems the value 16 was repeated

Comment: You're right, there is multiple data with the same ID I got on database.
[link](https://postimg.cc/9zBH97BZ)

Comment: `ID` column should always use `Unique` in an SQL Database :)

Comment: sure, this is my bad. I didn't recheck the data in database. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: No problem, If this answer helped you , consider marking it as the accepted answer, so we can help others on the StackOverflow Community with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the data type of `id (int)` and `_provinceSelected (String)`. Because the value of `id` in the DropdownMenuItem will return value in `onChanged` function. So you can change the data type of `id to String` or `_provinceSelected to int`. I hope it may help you.

Comment: This happened when I change _provinceSelected to int.
[link](https://postimg.cc/tsCGq4Qy)